# Zend Framework 2: Digits vs Int validator

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

**When (in what cases) we should use Digits validator and when we should use Int (IsInt) validator?**

According to http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.validators.html#zend-i18n-validator-int in some cases (depends on locale settings) values like 1,243 or 1.6546 may pass validation (look at the 3rd example from link above).

```
$validator = new Zend\I18n\Validator\IsInt();

$validator->isValid(1234);   // returns true
$validator->isValid(1234.5); // returns false
$validator->isValid('1,234'); // returns true <-------
```

This may lead to mess in some cases if we don't check this data again.

I see many projects/modules on github use Int validator to validate such data as id, phone or any other numeric data.
Shouldn't be more secure and safe to use Digits validator instead of Int?

**What advantages and disadvantages have Digits and Int validator?**

Answer (score 2):

`Zend\I18n\Validator\IsInt` is a validator which uses `NumberFormatter`([link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)) to validate a number assuming a locale. For example, the number 12345.67 is "12,345.67" in the US, "12 345,67" in France and "12.345,67" in Germany.

`Zend\Validator\Digits` is a primitive. It was created just to verify PHP's [type-casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) problems.

The answer is:

- Use `Zend\I18n\Validator\IsInt` in case you're working with locales.
- Use `Zend\Validator\Digits` in case you want to verify if a string has only digits in it (This means that any other sign like a thousand separator or a comma will not pass this validator) and a locale is not important for you.